# How can I retrieve the number of active "push subscribers" with Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I'm currently working with **parse.com** to send notifications to my users (on both iOS and Android). I want to find the answer to the following question : "**how many people receive my push notifications?**", just as with Mailchimp I can easily know the number of active subscribers to a certain mailing list.

However, that seems rather difficult to achieve as Parse doesn't seem to remove or tag "bounces".

For the moment, I haven't found anything:

- in the [parse install API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations)
- in their archive (except these questions created over 2 years ago: [q1](https://parse.com/questions/apple-feedback-service), [q2](https://parse.com/questions/tracking-application-uninstalls-for-push-notifications) and [q3](https://parse.com/questions/does-parsecom-save-installation-when-the-user-disable-push-notification-on-iphone))

I would be really interested for your inputs

Thanks

Comment: Did you ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: I thought my question was misleading and I've reformulated it. If I can't have more answers on this one, I'll understand there is no way to get the info I need.

Comment: I asked questions on the other one - what do you need it for, from a user point of view

Comment: I don't understand the "user point of view" part of your question. I have only 1 question: how many people receive my push notifications?

Comment: But do you just want to know for you, or you want to automatically do something with it? The former you can do from the analytics interface, the latter you can't (though you could perhaps have a cloud function which pushes and records the status)